# include jQuery into javascript and use it in imacros ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, imacros

I want to know how can I include jQuery library into javascript and use it in iMacros?

It goes like this. Into .js file I declare iMacros code as a variable

```
var someMacro;
someMacro ="CODE:";
someMacro +="TAB T=1 \n";
```

The code is actually larger and this is just small example. After I declared the variable I use commands like iimPlay, iimSet etc. to play the macro and set the variables inside the macro.

Now how can I include jQuery library into this so that I can use jQuery inside .js file and enhance my scripts ?

P.S. I found this on their forum but it didn't help me much since I didn't understand how to use it. Here is the link [Link to iopus forum about jQuery](http://forum.iopus.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=8956&p=31951&hilit=jquery#p31951)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've come with this this solution:

```
function loadScriptFromURL(url) {
    var request = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIXMLHttpRequest),
        async = false;
    request.open('GET', url, async);
    request.send();
    if (request.status !== 200) {
        var message = 'an error occurred while loading script at url: ' + url + ', status: ' + request.status;
        iimDisplay(message);
        return false;
    }
    eval(request.response);
    return true;
}

// load JQuery
loadScriptFromURL('http://mysupersecret.blob.core.windows.net/share/jquery-2.0.3.min.js');
$ = window.$,
JQuery = window.JQuery;
```

Trying to get jQuery from it's official CDN, I faced with the "setTimeout is undefined" error in iMacros. So I downloaded jQuery and modified *setTimeout* method to be *window.setTimeout*. This worked for me and so I had to place jQuery in my online shared location to use it from there. Hope this helps.

Comment: This will help a lot. Can you share an example of jQuery code used in iMacros with this?

Comment: Just search your JQuery file for a "setTimeout" string and prepend it with "window."
You can get mine from here: http://spprofessionals.blob.core.windows.net/share/jquery-2.0.3.min.js

Comment: IDK what iMacros is, but couldn't you just do something like `var setTimeout = window.setTimeout` in the global scope and then load jQuery from the CDN?

Comment: @dagg-nabbit, I've tried that as well — did not work for me))

Comment: @cyxou - can you share your js file again? I tried to change it by myself, but still get the same error. Can you please share it again? Thank you.

Comment: @cyxou Thank you mate :) still getting this stuff - ReferenceError: setTimeout is not defined, line 1 (Error code: -991) :) maybe, cuz of newer version of iMacros or Firefox.

Comment: @whitesiroi try this one https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4pXZXZ9UBTxx/jquery.js I've changed all occurrences of setTimeout to window.setTimeout

Comment: @cyxou thank you mate :) getting the same stuff :) I tried it before, changed every setTimeout, delete some of them, delete all of them, ...  -> ReferenceError: setTimeout is not defined, line 1 (Error code: -991) :)

Comment: @whitesiroi hm pretty strange.... actually I now use the [qwery](https://github.com/ded/qwery) library for basic dom operations. It's a light alternative to jQuery. Could you  please try it by downloading from here https://cloud.mail.ru/public/244mXJRs7tbQ/qwery.js  This one is my production minified version

Comment: @cyxou thank you, thank you :) it does work :) If you find out how to use jquery :) - plz, lemme know :)

Comment: @ cyxou I tried to use this with firefox version 54.0.1 and iMacros Version 8.9.7, but getting an error `Error: unsafe CPOW usage forbidden, line 2 (Error code: -991)`

Comment: @HardeepSingh, a lot has changed in latest versions of Firefox in terms of extensions. Use Pale Moon browser instead of Firefox, or use older version of Firefox, i.e. v42.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for putting this solution together. I loaded jQuery successfully, then created a bootstrap modal and appended it to the body. Next I attempted to load bootstrap.js and call the modal('show') method on the modal but to no avail. iMacros tells me that the function .modal doesn't exist.

```
loadScriptFromURL('http://localhost.com:7001/ybswcsstub/resources/plugins/jquery-1.10.2.min.js');

$ = window.$, JQuery = window.JQuery;

$.getScript('http://localhost.com:7001/ybswcsstub/resources/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js');

$('body').append('<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">' +
'  <div class="modal-dialog">'+
'    <div class="modal-content">'+
'      <div class="modal-header">'+
'        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>'+
'        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>'+
'      </div>'+
'      <div class="modal-body">'+
'        Some Modal'+
'      </div>'+
'      <div class="modal-footer">'+
'        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"     data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>'+
'        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>'+
'      </div>'+
'    </div>'+
'  </div>'+
'</div>');

$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

When I run I get the following error in iMacros
    TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function, line 211 (Error code: -991)

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm kind of stuck at this point :s

Edit:I had to use $.getScript to load the bootstrap.js (the .com in the domain is because of stackoverflowrestriction) as when I tried to use the loadScriptFromURL, I was getting the error

```
Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery, line 7 (Error code: -991)
```

Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: Faced with the same problem! I've managed to trigger a bootstrap modal by clicking on the corresponding button. Just create a button like this one: `var btn = "<button id='myButton' type='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='myModal'>Show Modal</button>"; $(btn).appendTo("body");` Of course you'll want to make this button invisible by applying display hidden to it. Once it appended to the body click on it with `$("#myButton").trigger("click");`. Hope this helps