# HTTP post in iMacros with Javascript for Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, imacros

I was making a automation script to extract some info from a website, And It's important to submit some info using POST method. Can anyone tell me how to use HTTP Post method with Imacro & javascript for firefox plugin. Below is the script which i found here : [Sending an HTTP Post using Javascript triggered event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873443/sending-an-http-post-using-javascript-triggered-event)
But it's giving me error when i play the same using Imacro player.

```
var url = "http://www.google.com/";
var method = "POST";
var postData = "Some data";
var async = true;

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onload = function () {
var status = request.status; // HTTP response status, e.g., 200 for "200 OK"
var data = request.responseText; // Returned data, e.g., an HTML document.
}

request.open(method, url, async);

request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
request.send(postData);
```

Comment: You have more comment than code there O_o

Comment: Cleaned, Also when i run this code it says : XMLHttpRequest is not defined.

Comment: Where are you running it? Which browser?

Comment: Firefox.25.0 and Imacro VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX

Answer (score 5):

`XMLHttpRequest()` is no longer supported in firefox 15+

You have to define it:

```
const XMLHttpRequest = Components.Constructor("@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1");
var request = XMLHttpRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

To run JavaScript in iMacros you can use this method.

```
URL GOTO=javascript:window.ScrollTo(0,150);
```

Try this method.

In your case it would look like this.

```
URL GOTO=javascript:var url = "http://www.google.com/";var method = "POST";var postData = "Some data";var async = true;var request = new XMLHttpRequest();request.onload = function () var status = request.status; var data = request.responseText; request.open(method, url, async);request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");request.send(postData);
```

Comment: Thank you IceD, But Would you be able to elaborate little more with actual code please.

Comment: There you go. But I don't know will this code work since I didn't test it.

Comment: Try out this solution. I noticed it has similarities with your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579587/include-jquery-into-javascript-and-use-it-in-imacros/20147634#20147634