# "Document not defined" Javascript with IMacros

Tags: javascript, jquery, imacros

I'm trying to run an IMacros macro written in javascript on a webpage, like so:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 18; i++) {
   document.querySelector(".foo table > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + i + ") > .goo:nth-child(2) > a").click();
   document.querySelector(".foo > a").click();

if (i % 17===0) {
    alert('Reset i');
    i = 1;
    }
}
```

Everything seems to work fine from the js console, but when I run the macro, I get:

```
"ReferenceError: document is not defined, line 2 (Error code: -991)"
```

I've loaded JQuery into iMacros with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579587/include-jquery-into-javascript-and-use-it-in-imacros), and put my code between:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //
});
```

But I keep getting this error if I use JQuery:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function, line 28 (Error code: -991)
```

And if I only use JS, I get the same 'document is not defined' error as before.

So my question is, do I need to define the document, and how do I do it?

Comment: try `jQuery` instead  `$`

Comment: Try it and let us know. I experimented a little bit with the function you put under "this" and it didn't really work.

Comment: @MohitArora Still getting the same error, either JQuery is not a function (if a replace $ for JQuery), or document not defined. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @macroscripts It's working for me if you replace the last URL to `spprofessionals.blob.core.windows.net/share/jquery-2.0.3.min.js`, as the link in the code given isn't working.

Comment: So replacing $ with jQuery will work? And any jQuery code will work when it's executed with iMacros?

Comment: Nope, in the end it didn't, I did use flish's solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never been able to load jQuery into an imacros script, but that's not such a big deal in the end.
To access the DOM you need to refer each element as:
`window.content.document.getElementsByClassName('foo')` for example. 
This will give you an array so be sure to pick each of the elements in the array you need:

```
var foo_class = window.content.document.getElementsByClassName('foo');

for (i=0;i<foo_class.length;i++){
//do something
}
```

Hope it helps

EDIT to add working example:

```
var links = window.content.document.getElementsByClassName('question-hyperlink');
var list=[]
for (i=0;i<links.length;i++){ 
txt=links[i].innerHTML;
list.push(txt);
}
number=links.length;
linkstexts=list.toString();
showme="number of links with class=question-hyperlink: "+number+"       text links with class=question-hyperlink: "+linkstexts;

iimDisplay((showme))
```

Copy the code in a macro.js and run it in firefox on stackexchage. It will count all the links with the class="question-hyperlink" and will display their respective text - you can see it in the green textbox under Play(Loop) button.

Comment: What are u using to run this code? FireBug console?

Comment: no, a .js script run directly in imacros for firefox. i'm not at the pc right now and it's rather late where i live, but tomorrow i'll post a working script that counts links or whatever.